# Question in Probability Theory

Tags: combinatorics

Lets say that I have 3 sets $A,B,C\subseteq E$ and I know $|E|,|A|,|B|,|C|,|\overline{A}|,|A\cap B|,|B\cap C|,|C\cap A|,|\overline{A}\cap B|,|\overline{A}\cap C|$ and $|A\cap B\cap C|$.

First of all is solvable?
If yes Is there any way that I can find $|\overline{A}\cap B\cap C|$?

Comment: Draw a Venn diagram. Mark which areas are known. Which follow?

Comment: Yhea a drew them but still I cant find something.Is the problem first of all solvable?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You know how many elements are in $B \cap C$, so that are both in $B$ and $C$.
Also you know how many are in $A \cap B \cap C$, so which are in all three. 
The difference are all elements that are in $B$ and in $C$ but *not* in $A$, so exactly in $\overline{A} \cap B \cap C$.

Comment: All the time I was taking $\overline{A} = A$ in the diagram venn for some reason... Thank you very much.

Answer (score 3):

Hint: Use the known values of $|A\cap B \cap C|$ and $|B \cap C|$.

Comment: Hello,I tried solve it with your hint but always end up in something that is always true.I dont know what I am doing wrong.Can you please help me?

Comment: @Marko Polo Perhaps try to identify the relevant regions in the Venn diagram.

Comment: Yhea still I cant understand how to use these relevant regions that you gave me couse if I remove the A and put A', then the $|A\cap B \cap C|$ set is gone,and in the first diagram are all known.

Comment: Nevermind I was taking $\overline{A} = A$ in the diagramm venn for some reason... Thank you